# Filtering many to many not contains with JPA Specification

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am implementing a database with two entities: Games and Genres

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Game extends NamedEntity {
  @Id
  private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
  private Set<Genre> genres;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Genre extends NamedEntity {
  @Id
  private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres")
  private Set<Game> games;
}
```

I am using JPA Specification for filtering, where I want: "All the games that do not have the genre 'Indie'"

```
public class GameSpecification implements Specification<Game> {
  @Override
  public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Game> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    Path<String> path = root.join("genres").get("name");
    return cb.notEqual(cb.lower(path), "indie");
  }
}
```

However, the result is counted based on genre entity and not on games entity. To be more clear, if a game contains the genre 'Indie' and has a total of 4 genres, I get this game in the resulted array 3 times repeated as exact the same instead of not getting it at all. If a game does not contain the genre 'Indie' then I get as many results as the genres that it has. If it has 5 genres I get it repeated 5 times.

If I do the opposite, i.e. find "All games that have the genre 'Indie'", where I just change the 'notEqual' to 'equal', then the filter works great.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: I believe you want `cb.isNotMember(cb.literal(“indie”), cb.lower(path))` instead of `notEqual`.

Comment: this does not compile, because the second parameter needs to be an Expression of Collection, where cb.lower(path) does not apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a solution. The reason for the complexity is that the SQL query  itself that we are trying to create is complex anyway by definition. So, we are trying to construct it via JPA objects. This is the solution:

```
Expression<Collection<Genre>> gameGenres = root.get("genres");
Subquery<Genre> genreSubquery = query.subquery(Genre.class);
Root<Genre> genreRoot = genreSubquery.from(Genre.class);

return cb.not(cb.exists(genreSubquery
                .select(genreRoot).where(
                        cb.equal(genreRoot.get("name"), "Indie"),
                        cb.isMember(genreRoot, gameGenres))));
```

In this solution we are utilizing JPA's subquery object and are building our final query with it. Eventually, I enabled SQL logging to bring up the final SQL query that is sent to my database.

```
select game0_.id as id1_2_, game0_.name as name2_2_ from game game0_ 
where not (exists (select genre3_.id from genre genre3_ where genre3_.name=? 
and (genre3_.id in (select genres4_.genres_id from game_genres genres4_ where game0_.id=genres4_.games_id))))
```